# OpenVDB does not show in render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, fire

I was trying to render out a sequence with OpenVDBs imported from Houdini and all of a sudden Cycles stopped rendering out the actual volume but only the reflections caused by it along with my model in the scene. I can see the VDBs and everything else in the scene without issues in the viewport even in rendered view. The issue persists with Eeevee as well.

I tried moving everything to a new project and it works for a little while but it disappears randomly in the render never to be seen again. I even reinstalled blender but that didn't help as well. If anyone can offer me some advice I would appreciate it as openVDB is just so amazing!

Here's what the render and viewport look like for the same frame:

[image]

[image]

My project file: https://we.tl/t-JHqUIjXRkV

Comment: I can't see any of the textures or even the volume in the blender file you uploaded.  Make sure you go under File -> External Data -> Pack All into .blend File so that the textures and everything is part of the blender file that you upload.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenince,   https://we.tl/t-qbLnYujag3                                                                   hope this one does the trick. I've been trying everything, render layers and all to no avail. please help. :(

Answer (score 1):

Turning the transparency off fixed everything.

Make sure to have density if you want transparent renders.

Comment: Dont forget to press the accept button on your answer :)